# Views exposed filter hide if less then 10 items

Tags: views

I want to show the exposed filter only when there are more than 10 items to filter. Any suggestion to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your theme's template.php file:

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$view){
  if ($view->name == 'VIEWNAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAYID' && $view->total_rows <= 10) {
    $view->exposed_widgets = '';
  }
}
```

This will remove all of the exposed filters. If you have more than one and you only want to remove a single exposed filter, you will have to parse that filter out of the `$view->exposed_widgets` html string.